# How do you solve for the intersection or multiplication rule of three dependent events?

Tags: probability

Yes I am not aware of how to edit in LaTeX or make elegant edits, so apologies for not being able to do such editing on my own.

I am aware that $P(A \cap B)$ for dependent events has $2$ variants based on the the $2!$ number of permutations in which $A$ and $B$ can be written.

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A | B) P(B)$$

$$P(B \cap A) = P(B | A) P(A)$$

My questions are,

1. What is the equivalent of this for three events given $A, B$ and $C$?
2. If I am right to assume, can we make $3!$ or $6$ versions of such a formula? What would they look like?
3. This one does not need me to see the formula of permuted variants, but what would the intersection of $n$ sets look like in some summary notation like summation?

I am particularly interested in wanting to see a sample problem and solution involving the intersection of three dependent events, but I don't think this site would find it nice if someone just goes around asking for x type of problem and solution even if it was simple just for me to get an illustration. But if it is allowed within the rules, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathbb P(A\cap B)\ne 0$ then
$$
\mathbb P(A\cap B\cap C)=\mathbb P(A)\ \mathbb P(B\mid A)\ \mathbb P(C\mid A\cap B)
$$
And there are $3!=6$ such versions.
For $n$ events $A_1,\ldots, A_n$, if $\mathbb P(A_1\cap\ldots\cap A_{n-1})\neq 0$,
$$
\mathbb P(A_1\cap\ldots\cap A_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb P\left(A_i\Biggm | \bigcap_{j=0}^{i-1} A_{j}\right)
$$
where it is assumed that $A_0=\Omega$.